# Всем привет! Не подскажете как соединить java и python?

Tags: java, python

Всем привет! я не знаю как подключить python и java. искал везде. Не поможете?)))
Нужно чтобы в одном проекте был код и джавы и пайтона

Comment: Что значит соединить или подключить?

Answer (score 2):

Был такой проект как **Jython**, и вроде как этот проект был нацелен на объединение всех самых лучших качеств обоих языков. Официальный сайт [здесь](http://jython.org). Но что-то нет уверенности, что проект ещё развивается, а начинать новые идеи на инструментах которые без массовой поддержки несколько рискованно. По этому лучше просто определитесь какие качества какого из языков нужны, составьте списком положительные и того языка и второго, и потом просто выберете для себя один.

Чем больше пользователей у какого-то инструмента тем больше изученных вопросов по нему, тем больше ответов.

Comment: По-моему, вопрос не про выбор языка, а про использовании одного в другом, только вот порядок непонятен пока

Comment: Да, в вопросе есть пока неясность)
Но jython самое близкое по релевантности, как мне кажется к формулировке